# When giving IPA codes and a translation, which comes first?

Tags: discussion

See [this question on prononciation](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/268/when-does-one-pronounce-the-s-in-plus). In his (excellent) answer, Gilles (btw, what's the formatting code to link to a user?) says:

- Lorsque « plus » est un **nom**, on prononce le `s` sourd. « Qui peut le plus peut le moins. » (proverbe, lit. « *Who can do the most can do the least* ») `[kipøləplyspøləmwɛ̃]`. « D'autant plus que ... » (« *all the more as* ») `[dotɑ̃plyskə]`.

Maybe it's because I'm not use to read IPA code and they scare the hair out of me, but wouldn't it be better to give the IPA codes first, as they relate to what's said in French, and then the translation? As in:

- Lorsque « plus » est un **nom**, on prononce le `s` sourd. « Qui peut le plus peut le moins. » `[kipøləplyspøləmwɛ̃]` (proverbe, lit. « *Who can do the most can do the least* ») . « D'autant plus que ... » `[dotɑ̃plyskə]` (« *all the more as* ») .

Comment: can't believe posting this made me pass for a robot

Comment: If you want to learn another language effectively, I strongly recommend you to learn the basic IPA sound of that language, your effort will be largely rewarded.

Answer (score 4):

I kind of get your point… But this seems like very fine nitpicking (and I know one thing or three about nitpicking).

Regarding the scare factor of IPA, I agree, but I can't think of any other way to indicate pronunciation precisely. I do explain the main point in words (“on prononce le `s` sourd”), but how do I convey what “s sourd” is without resorting to IPA? (I could say that it's a [voiceless alveolar sibilant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_alveolar_sibilant), but if you knew what that is, you didn't need to be told.)

---

Je vois ce que tu veux dire... Mais c'est vraiment de la tétracapillotomie (et je m'y connais).

Pour ce qui est de l'aspect effrayant de la notation phonétique, je suis d'accord, mais je ne vois pas d'autre méthode pour indiquer une prononciation précisément. J'explique le point essentiel en toutes lettres (« on prononce le `s` sourd »), mais comment expliquer ce qu'est un « s sourd » sans utiliser la notation phonétique ? (Je pourrais dire que c'est une [fricative alvéolaire sourde](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/API_s), mais si vous comprenez ce que c'est, vous n'avez pas besoin que je vous dise que c'en est une.)

Comment: C'est vrai que c'est capillotracté, et on ne va certainement pas s'amuser à créer une règle, mais je trouve que la deuxième forme est plus lisible. Note, je ne parle pas de ne pas mettre l'IPA (au contraire), mais bien de mettre _d'abord_ l'IPA juste derrière les mots auxquels il se rapporte, et ensuite seulement une éventuelle traduction anglaise. Le fait que je ne connaisse quasi pas l'IPA moi-même est sans rapport avec la question.

Comment: Il faut faire une suggestion d'édition, pour améliorer la lisibilité de la question peut-être?